# Accessing DataLayer Variables from Console

Tags: javascript

I have a Variable in my datalayer (Google Tagmanager) that I need to access through the console using javascript.

I tried all sorts of things (i am no JS coder) but no luck.

So how would I access a variable within the datalayer using Javascript in the console?

'-System Check if Click is AddToBasket Click' is the name of the variable.

Anyone?

Comment: Add debugger after the Google Tagmanager so you can access variable in the browser console.

Comment: Try writing `globalDataLayer` in your console inspector, you should see what's in your Google DataLayer